# How can I extend the Kogito DMN editor?

Tags: dmn, kogito

Is it possible to extend the Kogito DMN editor for example with additional buttons to provide additional custom functionality without cloning and building the whole [repository](https://github.com/kiegroup/kogito-editors-java)?

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial in [this blog post](https://blog.kie.org/2020/10/bpmn-and-dmn-standalone-editors.html) explain how to do it.

It boils down to integrate the DMN Editor as a dependency either from github CDN or as a NPM module. You then reference the JS API call in your HTML script. The tutorial show a complete end-to-end working demo.